# Oracle PL/SQL Conditional Declaration?

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, conditional-compilation

Can we do the conditional declarations of variables in pl/sql functions or procedures? For example can we do something like below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_total_sales(
    in_year PLS_INTEGER
) 
RETURN NUMBER
IS
    IF condtion THEN
       variable_name_1 BINARY_FLOAT;
    ELSE
       variable_name_2 NUMBER;
    END;

BEGIN
   --- Function Logic
END;
```

If the `condition` is met, I need to declare a variable called `variable_name_1` and if not I don't want to declare it and instead need to declare a variable called `variable_name_2`.

Comment: When is `condition` evaluated - at compile time, based on environment (e.g. dev/prod, customer licence) or are you trying to change this at run time for each call?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a possibilty since [Oracle 10](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/on-conditional-compilation).

Example:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test AS
  2    $IF $$test_on $THEN
  3      v1 BINARY_FLOAT;
  4    $ELSE
  5     v2 NUMBER;
  6    $END
  7    v boolean;
  8  BEGIN
  9   v := true;
 10  END test;
 11  /

Procedure created.

SQL> show errors
No errors.
SQL> --
SQL> ALTER PROCEDURE test COMPILE PLSQL_CCFLAGS = 'test_on:TRUE' REUSE SETTINGS;

Procedure altered.

SQL> --
SQL> BEGIN
  2  
  3    DBMS_PREPROCESSOR.print_post_processed_source (
  4      object_type => 'PROCEDURE',
  5      schema_name => 'SYSTEM',
  6      object_name => 'TEST');
  7  END;
  8  /
PROCEDURE test AS
v1 BINARY_FLOAT;
v boolean;
BEGIN
v := true;
END test;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> show errors
No errors.
SQL> --
SQL> ALTER PROCEDURE test COMPILE PLSQL_CCFLAGS = 'test_on:FALSE' REUSE SETTINGS;

Procedure altered.

SQL> --
SQL> BEGIN
  2  
  3    DBMS_PREPROCESSOR.print_post_processed_source (
  4      object_type => 'PROCEDURE',
  5      schema_name => 'SYSTEM',
  6      object_name => 'TEST');
  7  END;
  8  /
PROCEDURE test AS
v2 NUMBER;
v boolean;
BEGIN
v := true;
END test;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

SQL>

Comment: Whoa! Although 10g is an old piece of software, I've never seen that (obviously, never used it either). Cool!

Comment: You can do a lot actually. Steven Feuerstein did an excellent writeup https://stevenfeuersteinonplsql.blogspot.com/2019/03/an-introduction-to-conditional.html